# Can I use jasny-boostrap's rowlink on mobile only?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to use [Jasny Bootstrap's Row Link](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink) functionality on a responsive site. It's working fine, however, I would like to disable it on desktop screen sizes. Is there a way to do this? Or only enable it for screen sizes below the breakpoint? I'm using it on a dynamically created table, if that matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rowlink plugin uses JavaScript. That isn't easily controlled by media queries. Instead you could use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect touch devices.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody class="rowlink-touch">
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Next duplicate the rowlink CSS and add a `rowlink-touch` class which only works for touch devices.

```
html.touch .table.rowlink-touch td:not(.rowlink-skip),
html.touch .table .rowlink-touch td:not(.rowlink-skip) {
  cursor: pointer;
}

html.touch .table.rowlink-touch td:not(.rowlink-skip) a,
html.touch .table .rowlink-touch td:not(.rowlink-skip) a {
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

html.touch .table-hover.rowlink-touch tr:hover td,
html.touch .table-hover .rowlink-touch tr:hover td {
  background-color: darken(@table-bg-hover, 15%);
}
```

Last activate rowlink for `.rowlink-touch` elements.

```
$('.rowlink-touch').rowlink();
```

P.S. Note that I'm *not* using the `data-link` property.